# Infinitesimal Time Translation for a Conditional Expectation

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, correlation

(I am not sure what would be the proper title for the question)

Let us have a 2D random process $(A(t), X(t))$ and take both $A$ and $X$ to be just reals. We can write a conditional expectation of $A$ with respect to $X = x$:
$$
\langle a \rangle (x,t) = \bigl< A(t) \bigm| X(t) = x \bigr>.
$$
I am interested in expressing the following quantity
$$
\bigl< A(t + \Delta t) \bigm| X(t) = x \bigr>.
$$
in terms of $\langle a \rangle (x,t)$. My current guess is that
$$
\begin{multline}
\bigl< A(t + \Delta t) \bigm| X(t) = x \bigr>
= \langle a \rangle (x,t)\\[1ex]
+ \Delta t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle a \rangle (x,t)
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Bigl< [X(t + \Delta t) - X(t)]\,A(t) \Bigm| X(t) = x \Bigr> + \ldots.
\end{multline}
$$

Is this true and if so, why? (Take $A$ and $X$ to be smooth enough or whatever is needed). Just a reference would suffice.

**UPD** Considering uniformly distributed $X$ would suffice. If you take $X(t)$ to be a molecule's position in a flow, the flow is in-compressible.

---

My current thoughts were, that by introducing $\Delta X = X(t+\Delta t) - X(t)$, I can go as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\bigl< A(t + \Delta t) \bigm| X(t) = x \bigr>
&= \bigl< A(t + \Delta t) \bigm| X(t + \Delta t) - \Delta X = x \bigr>\\[1ex]
&= \Bigl< \bigl< A(t + \Delta t) \bigm| X(t + \Delta t) = x + \Delta X \bigr> \Bigm| X(t) = x \Bigr>\\[1ex]
&= \Bigl< \langle a \rangle (x + \Delta X, t+\Delta t) \Bigm| X(t) = x \Bigr>\\[1ex]
&= \langle a \rangle (t+\Delta t) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl< \Delta X \, A(t) \bigm| X(t) = x \bigr>,
\end{aligned}
$$
from which I got my guess. However, I am not sure why I can go from the first line to the second in the above.